# Spring Data Repository not working with Generics

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-repositories

I'm playing around with generics and Spring Data repository. I created a simple project with almost zero configuration, entities are in subpackage of main class.

Entity

```
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public class Person extends GenericEntity {

    private String name;

}


@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class GenericEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "TMS_INSERIMENTO")
    private LocalDateTime tmsInserimento;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "TMS_AGGIORNAMENTO")
    private LocalDateTime tmsAggiornamento;
}
```

Repository

```
public interface GenericRepository<T extends GenericEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer> {
}
```

Service

```
public List<Person> findAllPeople() {
    return genericRepository.findAll();
}
```

Call to findAll() throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not an entity: class com.example.demot.entity.GenericEntity; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.example.demot.entity.GenericEntity
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class GenericEntity <T extends GenericEntity> {

 ...
 }
```

And then

```
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public class Person extends GenericEntity<Person> {
 ...
}
```

And then you need the generic repository which should return generic entities not specific persons

```
 public interface GenericRepository extends JpaRepository<GenericEntity, Integer> {
 }
```

which can be called in service as

```
 public List<GenericEntity> findAllGenericEntities() {
        return genericRepository.findAll();
    }
```

And then you can also have a person repository

```
 public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
      }
```

which can be called in service as

```
 public List<Person> findAllPersons() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Comment: the point is to evoid boilderplate code such as a repository for every subclass of GenericEntity... also, GenericEntity is not an actual entity this means that findings all GenericEntity doesn't make sense.